# Why am I receiving a "Null value for non-nullable member" error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I utilizing EF 6.0 and receiving this error (Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'Details') on context.SaveChanges().  The value is NOT null but EF is still complaining that it is:

[image: Non-nullable rror]

This applies for both of the "CrashDump" objects.

Why would this be happening?

EDIT:

Here is all relevant code:

```
try
{
    if (Uri.CheckHostName(computer) != UriHostNameType.Unknown)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();

        pingOptions.DontFragment = true;
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcde");
        int timeout = 1;
        PingReply pingReply = pingSender.Send(computer, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);

        string uncPath = String.Format("\\\\{0}\\c$\\windows\\minidump", computer);

        if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Computer computerObj = (from c in context.Computers
                                    where c.Name == computer
                                    select c).First();
            List<CrashDump> dumps = computerObj.Dumps;

            Process bsodViewProcess = new Process();
            bsodViewProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            bsodViewProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = 
                string.Format("/loadfrom 1 /minidumpfolder \\\\{0}\\c$\\windows\\minidump /sxml dumps.xml", computer);
            bsodViewProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "BlueScreenView.exe";

            bsodViewProcess.Start();
            bsodViewProcess.WaitForExit();

            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("dumps.xml");

            List<CrashDumpDetails> lstDumpDetails =
                (from dump in xDoc.Element("crash_list").Elements("item")
                    select new CrashDumpDetails
                    {
                        DumpFile = dump.Element("dump_file").Value,
                        CrashTime = dump.Element("crash_time").Value,
                        BugCheckString = dump.Element("bug_check_string").Value,
                        BugCheckCode = dump.Element("bug_check_code").Value,
                        Parameter1 = dump.Element("parameter_1").Value,
                        Parameter2 = dump.Element("parameter_2").Value,
                        Parameter3 = dump.Element("parameter_3").Value,
                        Parameter4 = dump.Element("parameter_4").Value,
                        CausedByDriver = dump.Element("caused_by_driver").Value,
                        CausedByAddress = dump.Element("caused_by_address").Value,
                        FileDescription = dump.Element("file_description").Value,
                        ProductName = dump.Element("product_name").Value,
                        Company = dump.Element("company").Value,
                        FileVersion = dump.Element("file_version").Value,
                        Processor = dump.Element("processor").Value,
                        CrashAddress = dump.Element("crash_address").Value,
                        StackAddress1 = dump.Element("stack_address_1").Value,
                        StackAddress2 = dump.Element("stack_address_2").Value,
                        StackAddress3 = dump.Element("stack_address_3").Value,
                        ComputerName = dump.Element("computer_name").Value,
                        FullPath = dump.Element("full_path").Value,
                        ProcessorsCount = dump.Element("processors_count").Value,
                        MajorVersion = dump.Element("major_version").Value,
                        MinorVersion = dump.Element("minor_version").Value,
                        DumpFileSize = dump.Element("dump_file_size").Value,
                        DumpFileTime = dump.Element("dump_file_time").Value
                    }).ToList();

            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\c$\\windows\\minidump", computer)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\t{0}", file));

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                DateTime lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);

                var existingDump = from d in dumps
                                    where d.FileName == Path.GetFileName(file)
                                    where d.Time.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) 
                                            == File.GetLastWriteTime(file).Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                                    select d;

                if (existingDump.Count() == 0)
                {
                    CrashDump dump = new CrashDump();
                    dump.FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    dump.Time = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);

                    if (lstDumpDetails.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dump.Details = lstDumpDetails
                            .Where(d => Path.GetFileName(d.DumpFile) == dump.FileName)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
                    }

                    dumps.Add(dump);
                }
            }

            computerObj.Dumps = dumps;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
catch
{

}
```

Comment: Make your field nullable and update model please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: But the field is not null....so why would it say it is?

Comment: please see @Christos comment on answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be occurring because you're setting the value of `dump.Details` using `FirstOrDefault()` which results in `null` when the resulting collection contains no elements.

Check for that scenario and assign it a value to ensure that doesn't occur.

Answer (score 2):

This is reasonable because in a **non** nullable field you try to save a null value. You could fix this, making you field in the database to be nullable and then update your model.

Comment: In the screenshot from the question, there don't appear to be any `null` values.  Can you provide some more details as to how you came to this conclusion?

Comment: Exactly, the values of "Details" on all CrashDump objects are NOT null.

Comment: @slashp could you please then post all your code regarding your problem, because I think you might experience this due to complex types in entity framework, please have a look http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types for what I mean

Comment: I have posted all relevant code.  Is it possible that this is occurring because I did not add a primary key field for my dump details?

Comment: You have a table named `DumpDetails` without a primary key?  Perhaps I'm missing something, but it doesn't make any sense to me because you appear to have a foreign key; how else would entity framework be able to link those two records together?

Comment: Yeah you're right, I added the key and it looks like it's working now.  Before it was just appending the members of DumpDetails to the CrashDumps table.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  Joshua, would you like to post an answer so I can accept it?